# convert date string to mysql datetime field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of records with dates formatted as a string such as '04/17/2009'

I want to convert them to a mysql datetime field

I plan to use a foreach loop to read the old date value and insert the newly formatted value into a new field in each record

what would be the best way to convert that string...I thought php might have a way to do it automatically?

thanks

Answer (score 97, accepted):

First, convert the string into a timestamp:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($string);
```

Then do a

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Comment: or do it at once: date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($string));

Comment: Date returns a string. Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 25):

If these strings are currently in the db, you can skip php by using mysql's [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

I assume the strings use a format like `month/day/year` where `month` and `day` are always 2 digits, and `year` is 4 digits.

```
UPDATE some_table
   SET new_column = STR_TO_DATE(old_column, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

You can support other date formats by using [other format specifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: this would be a great way to go, too bad my db skills aren't up to the task

Comment: +1. Had to convert 3000 fake names exported by fakenamegenerator.com, and one field was named "birthday". Had every field stored in MM/DD/YYYY format as a VARCHAR field. This answer helped immensely.

Comment: must be the answer

Answer (score 8):

Use DateTime::createFromFormat like this :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i:s', $input_string.' 00:00:00');
$mysql_date_string = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can adapt this to any input format, whereas strtotime() will assume you're using the US date format if you use /, even if you're not.

The added 00:00:00 is because createFromFormat will use the current date to fill missing data, ie : it will take the current hour:min:sec and not 00:00:00 if you don't precise it.

Comment: Nice option for dates pre 1970

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = strtotime($oldtime);
```

Then use `date()` to put it into the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I assume we are talking about doing this in Bash?

I like to use sed to load the date values into an array so I can break down each field and do whatever I want with it. The following example assumes and input format of mm/dd/yyyy...

```
DATE=$2
DATE_ARRAY=(`echo $DATE | sed -e 's/\// /g'`)
MONTH=(`echo ${DATE_ARRAY[0]}`)
DAY=(`echo ${DATE_ARRAY[1]}`)
YEAR=(`echo ${DATE_ARRAY[2]}`)
LOAD_DATE=$YEAR$MONTH$DAY
```

you also may want to read up on the date command in linux. It can be very useful:
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date

Hope that helps... :)

-Ryan

Comment: It's PHP/MySQL. You check the tags once in a while ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE CONCAT( SUBSTRING(json_date, 11, 4 ) ,  '-', SUBSTRING( json_date, 7, 2 ) ,  '-', SUBSTRING( json_date, 3, 2 ) ) >= NOW();
```

## json_date ["05/11/2011"]