# Convert string from datetime php

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert date string to mysql datetime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501915/convert-date-string-to-mysql-datetime-field)

I have a DateTime column in MySQL database. I would like to convert Form text field data on POST (string) to DateTime before inserting into the database. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: This has been asked many many times.  Please search Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+php+strtotime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends entirely on what format your POST data is in. Quick/dirty/probably-will-blow-up-and-steal-your-belongings method is

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['yourfield']));
```

Answer (score 1):

`date()` function.

You can find the function in `php.net`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on format of MySQL date time field and the format of the form field. Normally db datetime is Year-Month-day Hour:min:sec for example, "2011-10-24 14:25:20". Now to convert form submitted date string to datetime, do the following:

> $date = strtotime($_POST['form_date']);
>
> $DatabaseDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);

Now you can use the above $DatabaseDate to insert datetime into database:

> @mysq_query("INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (id, date_test) VALUES (2,
>   '$DatabaseDate')");

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

instead of strtotime($_POST['yourfield'])
use the function mktime, in that way you dont need to worry about the string format