# jQuery UI DatePicker - Date Format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a simple datepicker on my site.

Example is : [here](http://apili.net/code/datepicker/)

I need the date format to be YYYY-MM-DD **ONCE** the date has been selected - This so that it can be entered into the DB in a suitable format.

How do I achieve this.

Any help much, much appreciated.

Comment: What server-side language are you using?

Comment: Or you can see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501915/convert-date-string-to-mysql-datetime-field

Comment: Thanks Khronos I'll manipulate the date for the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use -

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})
```

Comment: Ah ha! Thats done the trick. I was trying options in the string, Thanks for that