# How do I convert the following to insert into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following date/time: `Thu, 26 Jun 2014 07:13:32 +0000`

I need to convert this to the format for inserting into mysql: `2014-06-26 07:13:32`

How would I go about doing so?

I tried doing `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(Thu, 26 Jun 2014 07:13:32))` but it gives me the wrong time (specifically hour).

Comment: Why dont you use strtotime to store time in your database example `strtotime('Thu, 26 Jun 2014 07:13:32 +0000')`

Comment: Because the database uses datetime and already has a ton of data in it and I'm doing an import of additional data.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501915/convert-date-string-to-mysql-datetime-field

Comment: I used the answer from that but I am getting the wrong time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for me and gives the result you specify above:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); 
print date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("Thu, 26 Jun 2014 07:13:32"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to the desired format easily using DateTime class

```
$date = new DateTime('Thu, 26 Jun 2014 07:13:32 +0000');
$modified_date=$date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $modified_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the time zone causing the time to change try this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('Thu, 26 Jun 2014 07:13:32 +0000'));
```