# Convert date to integer (timestamp)

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

In mysql , the `data type` is `integer`... And I want to save date as `1422104820` format (*timestamp*).

```
$Date = $_POST['Date'];
$Time = $_POST['myTime'];
$Date1 = $Date.$myTime;

insert into table ('date') values ($Date1);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert date string to mysql datetime field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501915/convert-date-string-to-mysql-datetime-field)

Comment: `in mysql , the data type is integer` while it properly should be `timestamp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of this two ways to get the `timestamp`:

#### METHOD #1: Structured style.

```
// Use the strtotime() function
$timestamp = strtotime($Date1);
```

#### METHOD #2: Object-oriented style.

```
// DateTime class.
$date = new DateTime($Date1);
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
```

---

> **NOTE ABOUT PERFORMANCE:**
>
> The **structured** style ( `strtotime()` ) is faster than the **Object-oriented** style ( `DateTime` ).

You can see an interesting benchmark of this two ways to get the `timestamp` here:

 http://en.code-bude.net/2013/12/19/benchmark-strtotime-vs-datetime-vs-gettimestamp-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

The function you search for is [strtotime();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).