# Converting String into Date from HTML Form

Tags: php, date, converters

i collect date formats like this :

Day

```
<select id="DOBDay" name = "DOBDay" class="pure-input-1-4">
<option>Date Of Birth Day</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
```

Month

```
<select id="DOBMonth" name = "DOBMonth" class="pure-input-1-4">
<option>Date Of Birth Month</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
```

Year

```
<select id="DOBYear" name = "DOBYear" class="pure-input-1-4">
<option>Date Of Birth Year</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
```

After the form has been posted ,it gets collects like this :

```
$DOBDay = $_POST['DOBDay'];
$DOBMonth = $_POST['DOBMonth'];
$DOBYear = $_POST['DOBYear'];
```

How do i get this into a dateformat to be stored into a MySQL date feild.
I have searched the web and cannot find this example anywhere for assistance.

Comment: Just `$DOBYear.'-'.$DOBMonth.'-'.$DOBDay ` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert date string to mysql datetime field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501915/convert-date-string-to-mysql-datetime-field)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$DOBDay = '21';
$DOBMonth = '09';
$DOBYear = '1986';  
$full_date = $DOBYear.'-'.$DOBDay.'-'.$DOBMonth;
echo $full_date;`
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of possibilities.. mktime for example.

```
// if you need a timestamp
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$DOBMonth, $DOBDay, $DOBYear);

// or datetime
$datetime = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql use yyyy-mm-dd format. so you should store the value in something like :

```
$DOBDay = '21';
$DOBMonth = '09';
$DOBYear = '1986';  
$date = $DOBYear.'-'.$DOBMonth.'-'.$DOBDay;
echo $date;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$date= $_POST['DOBDay']."/". $_POST['DOBMonth']."/".$_POST['DOBYear'];
```