# using a variable outside while loop

Tags: php

I am trying to use a variable outside of a while loop which is in a foreach loop, but it works in the loop and displays the correct date. But when used outide the loop it displays incorrect date `01/01/1970`.

I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Many thanks.

```
  $Destdate = $_POST['box_rtv'];
  $brtvarray = array();
  $brtvarray = $Destdate;
  $ddate = array();

  foreach ($brtvarray as $destbox) {
    $sql = "SELECT destroydate FROM act WHERE item = '".$destbox."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error selecting item: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while ($row_code = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $ddate[] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row_code['destroydate']));
      }
    }
  }

    $company = strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['rtvcompany']));
    $activity = "Box Retrieval";
    $address = ucwords(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']));
    $service = ucwords(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['service']));
    $success = 'SUCCESS';
    $authorised = ucwords(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['ls_name_usr']));
    $dept = strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['rtvdept']));
    $boxitems = $_POST['box_rtv'];
    $box = implode(",",$boxitems);
    $array = array();
    $array = $boxitems;

    foreach ($array as $boxes) {
        $outString .= "$box" . "  ";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `act` (service, activity, department, company, address, `user`, `date`, destroydate, item, new) VALUES ('$service', '$activity', '$dept', '$company', '$address', '$authorised', NOW(), '".$ddate."', '$boxes', 1)";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ('Error inserting box:' . mysqli_error($conn));

        $sql = "UPDATE boxes SET status = 1 WHERE customer = '$company' AND custref = '$boxes'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ('Error updating box:' . mysqli_error($conn));

        $sql = "UPDATE files SET boxstatus = 1 WHERE customer = '$company' AND boxref = '$boxes'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ('Error updating filebox:' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    $json = array($box);
    $result = json_encode($json);
    echo $result;
```

Comment: share sample value for `$row_code['destroydate']` ?

Comment: @C2486 should be: `29/05/018` Thanks

Comment: Are you sure year is `018` and not `2018` or `18` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to have array of dates, which is $ddate, then this line

```
$ddate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row_code['destroydate']));
```

should be:

```
$ddate[] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row_code['destroydate']));
```

Comment: That works but not when I use variable in mysql query. it enters date as `0000-00-00`. I am trying to do a lookup on a table and then use that var $ddate in a foreach loop for a mysql insert. I shall update my code to reflect this.

Comment: If `$row['destroydate'] = "29/05/2018"`, then `$ddate[]=$row['destroydate']`

Comment: If in your MySQL table your field format is `datetime` then you should convert your date to proper format before using it in INSERT query, which is `Y-m-d H:i:s`. You can read more about in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501915/convert-date-string-to-mysql-datetime-field

Comment: It is a date field. Thanks

Comment: you have $ddate as an array, but in your second foreach loop, you're using it as a scalar in your INSERT query. Echo the resulting SQL query string and see what it looks like. I think you'll find it's not what you expected.

Comment: Now, when I can see full code, I want to propose some improvements for you, to make your code more readable and supported by other people. It's better to name variables by their meaning and using proper words for that. For example the `$ddate` var might be `$boxDestroyDates` or `$box_destroy_dates` this much more readable and understandable. Also I dont' understand why you need to copy this var `$boxitems` to `$array` this looks strange. And I can't see any validating/filtering on input data from $_POST which is not secure and might lead to critical errors. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using any standard format for `year` in `date` so first you need to make it standard either full year `2018` or short `18`

```
$row_code['destroydate'] = '29/05/018';
$dt_arr = explode("/",$row_code['destroydate']);
$dt_arr[2] = 2000+$dt_arr[2];
$dt = implode("/",$dt_arr);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dt);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1022205)