# I'm having trouble running this php code with my database in phpmyadmin in cpanel

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble running this code in phpmyadmin. It is not storing anything in the RESERVATIONS table. I've spent hours trying to figure this out. I tried putting the queries in manually in phpmyadmin and that was successful. However, running it in the php file is another story. The table is called RESERVATIONS and it has columns:

[image of table RESERVATIONS columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cFNG.png)

```
<?php
    require 'dbconfig/config.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:#bdc3c7">

    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <center>
            <h2>Registration Form</h2>
            
        
        <form class="GuestForm">
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required>
    <hr>
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required>
    <hr>
    <label for="phoneNum">GuestPhone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phoneNum" id="phoneNum" required>
    <hr>
    <label for="emailaddr">GuestEmail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="emailaddr" id="emailaddr" required>
    <hr>
    <label for="dateNtime">DateTime:</label>
    <input type="text" name="dateNtime" id="dateNtime" required>
    <hr>
    <label for="partySize">Party Size:</label>
    <input type="number" name="partySize" id="partySize" min="0" max="10" required>
        <input name="submit_btn" type="submit" id="signup_btn" value="Create Reservation"/><br>
</form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Submit button clicked") </script>';
                $fname = $_POST['fname'];
                $lname = $_POST['lname'];
                $phoneNum = $_POST['phoneNum'];
                $emailaddr = $_POST['emailaddr'];
                $dateNtime = $_POST['dateNtime'];
                $partySize = $_POST['partySize'];
                
                
                    $query = "SELECT dateNtime from RESERVATIONS WHERE dateNtime = '$dateNtime'";
                    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                    //$length = mysql_field_len(username, 0);
                    
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0) 
                    {
                        // There is already a reservation for that particular date and time
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("There is already a reservation for that particular date and time") </script>';
                    }
                    else{
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT SUM(table_size) AS value_sum FROM DININGTABLES WHERE occupied = 0'); 
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
                        $sum = $row['value_sum'];
                        echo $sum;
                        
                        
                        $query = "INSERT into RESERVATIONS(reservation_id, registered_user, username, fname,lname,phoneNum, emailaddr, dateNtime, partySize) values('NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL','$fname','$lname', '$phoneNum', '$emailaddr', '$dateNtime', '$partySize')";
                        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                        
                        if($query_run)
                        {
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Reservation created but not really") </script>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Error!") </script>';
                        }
                        
                
                
                
                
            }
            }
        ?>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This isn't meant to be a public thing, just for a school project. I'm not concerned about security since it won't be deployed

Comment: What is the result after you submit the form? Alert Error? or Alert Reservation created? In case of error, display error details with `mysqli_error($con);`.

Comment: You have $con and $conn. (are you using two different db connections ? ). Try changing $con to $conn (or vice versa)

Comment: Yeah I changed them. Currently, I'm just concerned with getting data into the table.

Comment: I should mention that ```<?php
    require 'dbconfig/config.php';
?>``` is working

Comment: **Yeah I changed them** - please amend your code to reflect the changes so that we can further check.

Comment: Try to change `'NULL'` to just simply `NULL` in your insert query. Variables are also not escaped and can cause query errors. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your insert statement according to your schema.

```
$query = "INSERT into RESERVATIONS(reservation_id, registered_user, username, fname,lname,phoneNum, emailaddr, dateNtime, partySize) 
values('NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL','$fname','$lname', '$phoneNum', '$emailaddr', '$dateNtime', '$partySize')";
```

For example:

1. `reservation_id` is not nullable, yet you are attempting to pass NULL as the value. Since this is an auto-incrementing primary key, you can probably remove this column from your insert statement.
2. `phoneNum` is an integer, yet you are attempting to pass a string.  You may need to parse this value to make sure it's numeric.
3. `dateNtime` may need to be parsed before it can be inserted into SQL. See this post for more details: [convert date string to mysql datetime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501915/convert-date-string-to-mysql-datetime-field)
4. `partySize` is an integer, yet you are attempting to pass a string.  You may need to parse this value to make sure it's numeric.
5. Like others have mentioned in the comments, you may want to drop the single quotes around `'NULL'` and instead just pass `NULL`.

These are just a few things you can try!

Please let me know if you still have issues inserting your data and share any error messages as that will be helpful in resolving any remaining issues!